# Analyzing the behavior of a non-linear model

Tags: random-forest, nonlinear

I am working with a random forest model and would like to better understand how the variables impact the forest output.  Using partial plots is useful, but this is basically a linear treatment of the model, because it assumes there is no interaction between the variables.  Are there known methods for evaluating the non-linear-ness of the a random forest model or for analyzing how variables interact with each other within the model?